# RxJS conditional switch throttle

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have a tab bar with tabs and one active tab and I want to prevent multiple clicks on a single tab within a .

I would like to implement the following behavior:

Original state with each case: Active tab is tab A.

- If I once press on tab A, I want the A tab event.
- If I repeatably press on tab A, I want to have throttled A events.
- If I press tab B, I want to have the B event.
- If I repeatably press tab B, I want to have the first B event and throttle the other B events.

In other words:

- press tab event -> if same tab -> throttle-> tab event
- press tab event -> if not same tab -> tab event

How do I implement this behavior with RxJS?

```
this.onTabSelect$.pipe( 
    // TODO ?
).subscribe(async (tab: Tab) => {
    // tab event
});
```

Thanks!

Here is my current (finally working) state: [code example](https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-sky-i4zsv?file=/src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here and updated my example:

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53623221/rxjs-throttle-same-value-but-let-new-values-through/53627167#53627167)

[code example](https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-sky-i4zsv?file=/src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`throttle`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/throttle) and choose `interval(throttle_time)` or `of(0)` depending on the value of the selected tab.

```js
this.onTabSelect$.pipe(
    throttle((tab: Tab) => interval(tab.id === this.currentTab ? interval(THROTTLE_TIME) : of(0))
).subscribe(async (tab: Tab) => {
    // tab event
});
```

`throttle` takes as argument a function which, given the emitted value of the initial observable, returns an observable that will be subscribed to, and once such observable emits a value, the throttle timer will be disabled.

So we can decide, depending on whether the selected tab is the current tab or not, whether to throttle the observable for a given time, or emit right away effectively disabling the throttle timer because the tab is a different one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It got me one step closer. There is just one edge-case that I did not manage to find a solution.
see here: https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-sky-i4zsv?file=/src/app/app.component.ts
edge case: tab A is selected (default), and then fast double click on tab B.
If the tab changes, it always emits two events instead of one initially.